# How to remove a variable from request after use in Sightly?

Tags: sightly

I've a situation where I needed a request attribute to identify from which container component the child components are rendered. Based on which I am changing the behaviour of child component. However, I want to clean off the request attribute after the child components are rendered. How do I achieve this in sightly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a script (say clear.js) to clear request variable:

```
/*
 * Clear request objects
 */

"use strict";

use([], function () {
    request.removeAttribute("variableName");
    request.removeAttribute("variableName");
});
```

Call this script from your sightly code:

```
<sly data-sly-use="clear.js"> </sly>
```